# How to check null value in the parse table using android?

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing

I have not any idea about this.
For how to check the `null` value from the **parse** table from his column.
In this column to define "(undefined)".

I try like this.

```
if (pList.getString("zip") == "nil") {
    Log.e("in Plist if condition", ":::" + pList.getString("zip").length());
} else {
    Log.e("in Plist if else condition", ":::" + pList.getString("zip"));
}
if(pList.getString("zip") == "(undifine)"){ 
}
```

This type of try but I not getting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `null` like

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty("zip")) {
 }
```

It will **Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.**

#### See this link for [TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 1):

null is null not nil in java (you had it correct in the title):

```
if (pList.getString("zip") == null) {}
```

should work as a null check.

Alternative you could use try catch:

```
try {
   Log.e("in Plist if condition", "::: "
    + pList.getString("zip").length());
catch(NullPointerException exp) { 
   Log.e("in Plist if condition", exp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on what kind of datastructure your pList is, but my general answer would be:
You might want to compare objects with null, this will give check whether the string object(myString) exist or not, for example 
if (myString==null) than blabla...
But if you want to compare if the value of a myString equals to "null" you can use for example 
if (myString.equals("null")) than blabla...

Comment: i try this already but is not i got solution. in parse table default value is (undifine).

Comment: so try to compare it to undefined...if (myString.equals("undefined")) than blabla...that should work if you have a table full of STRING values "undefined"...
***For some reasons I have a feeling that your program throws exception to you saying that some variable(like pList) is undefined, if it is the case you just need to declare your variable, for example:
String myString="valueOfMystring";